# Howto Seed / Export Consul-backed Vault Store?

Tags: configuration, docker, consul

I can see howto seed / export data into and out of consul, at least using the HTTP interface (see [here](https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/kv.html) (or even [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-replicate))).

But how do you seed / export a consul-backed vault store? The only way I can see is to `vault write secret/foo value=bar`. And I'm not sure how that would work, when I'm using Terraform to push a dockerized, consul-backed vault instance to the cloud?

Comment: // , Have you considered Consul's Snapshot Agent? https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/snapshot/agent.html  You can also use consul-replicate to replicate the vault-specific elements of the Consul KV store that don't relate to a specific cluster. If you want more details I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted something like envconsul, which let's us run a binary with some extra vars injected into the environment.

But as I read envconul's [docs](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul#vault-secrets), it looks like it also interfaces with Vault.